# binary operator / cannot be applied to operands of type Int and Double

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Hello brand new to Swift, and programming in general. Going through an exercise the code given is exactly:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let height = 12
let width = 10


let area = height * width

let areaInMeters = area / 10.762
```

But I get the error, "binary operator / cannot be applied to operands of type Int and Double".

After some digging around I found you can't operate on both an Integer and a Double. So I changed the last line to:

```
let areaInMeters = (Double)area / 10.762
```

Then I get the error, "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by a ;" and it wants me to put the ; after area. None of this is making any sense to me.

Using El Capitan beta and Xcode 7 beta.

Comment: `let areaInMeters = Double(area) / 10.762`

Comment: Thanks, I was just going to post I got that, hah. Completely my fault. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

height and width will both be inferred as of type Int. Therefore area is also of type Int whilst 10.762 is a Double.

And in Swift safety is paramount so you'll need to have both operands of same type.

Solution is (as Eric D. suggested) is to convert area to a Double:

```
let areaInMeters = Double(area) / 10.762
```

Answer (score 1):

Try instead adding a decimal point and a zero to the end of your height and width.

Like so:

let height = 12.0
let width = 10.0

And you won't have to worry about having to deal with an Integer.
Hope this helps. Happy Coding!